# Explain NS3Error and suggest any solution?

Tags: compiler-errors

Please someone explain this error and also suggest some solution how to fix it.

Build failed:

```
task in 'ns3-lte' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140264885380880: cxx lte-amc.cc -> lte-amc.cc.1.o}
['/usr/bin/g++', '-O3', '-g', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-march=native', '-fstrict-overflow', '-Wstrict-overflow=2', '-std=c++11', '-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations', '-fstrict-aliasing', '-Wstrict-aliasing', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-I.', '-I..', '-I/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi', '-I/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi', '-I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0', '-I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0', '-DNS3_BUILD_PROFILE_OPTIMIZED', '-DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_NETS_H=1', '-DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H=1', '-DHAVE_PACKET_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_TUN_H=1', '../src/lte/model/lte-amc.cc', '-c', '-o', '/home/buzafar/mongo-c-driver-1.8.2/mongo-cxx-driver/build/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/build/src/lte/model/lte-amc.cc.1.o']
```

Comment: You should explain what you did to get this error.

Comment: Not only that, but why do you have a version of the MongoDB C++ driver under a directory called `mongo-c-driver-1.8.2`, and then why is there a version of the NS3 library bundled under that? What is going on here?

Comment: There also should be some output that preceded this error that contains a compiler error message. Providing that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Here is the output:                                                                                                
[2118/2471] Compiling src/lte/model/lte-control-messages.cc
../src/lte/model/lte-amc.cc: In static member function ‘static int ns3::LteAmc::GetRbFromTb(int, int)’:
../src/lte/model/lte-amc.cc:271:10: error: ‘h_rb’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   return h_rb;
          ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

Comment: Well, the compiler error should be pretty clear, no? You have set things up so that warnings about potentially un-initialized variables being used have been promoted to errors, and such a warning fired, resulting in an error which terminated compilation. You should either fix the issue in the code (if the variable really is used without being initialized, that is a potentially bad bug in the code), or you should suppress the warning somehow, or you should stop building in a mode where warnings are errors. Reading the compiler output is the only way to proceed here.